# Identity Leakage - Universal Financials

Tags: tax-law

I did my 2018 tax return with Universal Financials, LLC, and I got my tax review copy online. Then one of my colleague came and said he also did tax return filing through the same agency and he got my tax review copy, which includes my name, address,social security number, and other tax related info. So I dont know how to protect my details from others and also is that details shared to anyone else or not. Is there any way to ask for the compensation to the above said agency? or should I ask the agency to provide me a documented agreement saying that if anything happens in future, they will take the full responsibility. Or shall I move a legal case against them?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Terms and Conditions](https://www.universalfinancials.com/TermsConditions.html) of Universal Financials' site - which you agreed to when you used their service by "click signing" a contract - they state that they are not liable for the security of your personal and financial information.

You could take them to civil court for damages, but your contract with them absolves them of liability. And, they would surely not sign an individual contract with you to safeguard your information in the future, as that would open them up to signing such a contract with all users and as a result be liable for data leakage.

Your only recourse is to not use their service; their recourse is to close your account.

> Date Security & Integrity:
>
> MetaFin Consulting, LLC has reasonable technical and organizational
>   Security measures in place to protect personal information against
>   unauthorized disclosure or access and against any other unlawful forms
>   of processing. However, these measures are not absolute. In addition,
>   the transmission of data over the Internet by its nature entails the
>   use of systems under the control of third parties, and as a result
>   MetaFin Consulting, LLC cannot ensure the security of such systems.
>
> Force Majeure:
>
> MetaFin Consulting, LLC is not responsible for any delay or failure in
>   performance of the website in whole or in part for any reason
>   including, without limitation: fires, floods, storms, earthquakes,
>   civil disturbances, disruption of telecommunications, hacker attack,
>   governmental action, computer viruses, data corruption, incompatible
>   or defective equipment, software or services or otherwise.

Comment: tbh just because they write it in their terms of service doesn't releases them of their liability. Like you can't write down "if I accidentally kill you I'm free from any liability". Pretty sure OP could take them to court and court would remind the company to be more cautious with personal data. No fine but a scolding.